# FLV's not caching

Tags: actionscript-3, caching, flv

working on a project with a custom flv player.
Everything works as it should

However, the flv's don't seem to be caching, if I play the video once, close the player, and replay again, the video has to cache -load entirely again before the video starts playing.
Can anyone suggest troubleshooting steps since, as far as i know, this should not be the way it works...

Comment: It's however the server serving the FLV chooses to set the necessary headers that will influence how it is being cached. Where is the video coming from? What server are you using? What headers are sent with the video? Is it even over HTTP? If not, then normal HTTP caching rules do not apply.

Answer (score 0):

As spender mentioned, if you are not loading the flv via http, then caching does not apply.

You might want to check out Greensock's LoaderMax, as it provides highly configurable and easy-to-use video playback functionality which has ironed out many of the kinks in Adobe's own video player classes:

http://www.greensock.com/loadermax